# Why is my icon for browser tab not showing up?

Tags: html, favicon

I want to make a favicon for my web page. I found a sample but it's not working for me. Can someone please help me get it to work. On the index page of the web site I put this in the  of the page.

```
 <!--
 <![if !IE>
  <link rel="icon" href="http://mywebsiteurl/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
 <![endif]>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mywebsiteurl/images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
 !-->
```

Can I put this on specific pages that I want to display the favicon or does it have to be somewhere at the root of the site?

If you can think of any solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: i use <link rel="shortcut icon" this for all the browsers, it is working for me. can u check once

Comment: The last link tag is within a comment block, so it will be ignored by all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, your comment end was in the wrong place

```
<!--
<![if !IE>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://mywebsiteurl/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<![endif]>
!-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mywebsiteurl/images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IE conditional comments for a reason, it looks like your comment syntax is off. [You can read more about them here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Otherwise, the conditional comments aren't specifically needed for a favicon; your first tag looks good to me.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Yes, you can use unique favicons for individual pages, but browsers go cache crazy and will usually show the most recent icon for that domain unless otherwise instructed. For example: if you set an icon on your home page, but then didn't set one on a subpage, it would likely keep the home page's icon.